# 'onclick' event in an HTML block not working on mobile devices

Tags: html, onclick

I have a flexbox table with two JS charts in its cells. To each chart block I added the 'onclick' event. When you click a chart, the 'onclick' event should redirect you to a certain page. It works fine on desktop browsers, however on mobile devices you have to tap the cell about 10 times to trigger the event. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<div class="Table-row">
  <div class="Table-row-item padding_mod chart_mod">$2,456</div>
  <div class="Table-row-item chart_mod chart_no_pad_mod">
    <div class="chart_container chart_mod">
      <div id="allBranchNutChart" onclick="window.location ='sales_details.html';" class="chart_item table_mod"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Table-row-item u-Flex-grow2 chart_mod chart_no_pad_mod">
    <div class="chart_container chart_mod chart_no_pad_mod">
      <div id="allBranchColumnChart" onclick="window.location ='sales_details.html';" class="chart_item table_mod"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can  test this

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function redir_sales_details()
{
  window.location='sales_details.html';
}
</script>
<div id="allBranchColumnChart" onclick="redir_sales_details()" class="chart_item table_mod"></div>
```

Just make some few functions

Comment: No, unfortunately this doesn't work either. I've already tried this method.